Can a hot water heater be repaired with corrosion at the base of the input and output pipes?
This is an 80 gallon hot water heater.  Leaks at the base of the pipes shown fill the small basins in the top of the heater over a period of about 1 to 2 hours.  The catch basin at the base of the hot water heater eventually gets up to about 1/2 inch of water but never enough to reach the drain hole in the side of the basin.  The heater does not leak from the bottom and otherwise performs well, providing plenty of hot water. I doubt that the anode has ever been replaced or the heater ever flushed. I estimate the heater to be 10+ years old.  Can the point of attachment of the pipes to the heater be repaired?  I would like to get some advice before calling in a plumbing company that might prefer to just sell me a new heater than consider a repair.


10+ years, they won't be just trying to sell a new one.  Can it be repaired, probably, but it is a pressurized tank with limited maintenance done to it.  The labour to repair that leak will be near a new tank and no guaranty the tank will not develop another leak in the next hour.

The joints all appear to be sweated (soldered) copper tubing. All modern installations have insulating joints (so called "dielectric unions") usually built into flexible supply lines. It would not surprise me if the joints at water heater were overheated by sweating in place which would almost certainly be contrary to the installation instructions for this water heater. This could have damaged the plastic inserts in the metal joints. Get a new heater and have it installed properly.

All of the joints do not have to be dielectric unions, but there should be one in each line and usually it is at joint at the water heater.

Start by checking the sacrificial anode.  If that is gone, then probably, so is the water heater.  Regrettably you will not be able to buy an 80 gallon electric resistance tank, but you will be able to buy a heat pump unit, which could pay for itself in a couple of years with energy savings, provided you can tolerate the dehumidification and chilling it will bring to the room.

Do yourself a favor, get a new Hot Water tank.  Why waste time fooling with something that has reached the end of it's useful life.
When The tank is replaced use dielectric nipples on both hot and cold ports as others have suggested.

Bad news
That corrosion probably spread on the inside of the tank, and the tank will leak soon.
As a temporary fix, unscrew the pipes, clean the rust and use teflon tape to seal the leak

To unscrew the pipes they must be cut first. This could done easily, but if you woud do this, then the best connection would be to use flexible supply lines which each would have a dielectric coupling on the end which screws onto the water heater. The other end of each flexible supply line would connect to the copper tubing. That connection could be either a sweated joint or a compression fitting, both types are available AFIK. If you would do this and the taknk would later fail, you could reuse the existing piping. Dielectric union couplings can be screwed on or off without cutting any pipes.

@Jim cut first?  Drain them, heat a joint up with a propane torch and pop it off vertically (warning: splattering solder).  This is copper pipe 101 type stuff.  But I quite agree with flexible hoses, as the rigidity of the connection is placed under strain by temperature differences.

Suppose you don't want to use a torch. [After turning off the valve] cut the line in the correct location with a tubing cutter and unscrew the riser from the tank. Ream the cut end inside and outside, and install the new flexible lines with dielectric unions. Lots of people would rather install a compression fitting than use solder.

Don't these tank WHs come with a pair of special short nipples (male threads on both ends) that the dielectric unions screw onto (special in that they are lined with a thermal insulator) ?
